# Discord.py Send the content after the command in a file.txt

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a command to my Discord Bot.
That if I do `!txt You can only see this on PC` it will send a file named file.txt with the content being what I wrote after the command.

I had no success trying it so there is no code to show. This is what the example should display:

[image: example]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload this as a [file](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File). You can then use `BytesIO` to make the string into a file.

```py
bytes_io = BytesIO(msg.encode('utf-8'))
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=bytes_io, filename='message.txt'))
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Respons.
I tried your code but the "BytesIO" after bytes_io =  is underlined and I guess thats because I forgot to import something but trying to import "BytesIO" doesnt work since it says "No module named 'BytesIO'" . After I put BytesIO at the top the underlined part goes away but like I mentioned the module doesnt exists.
This is the code I used
client.command()
async def file(ctx, *, msg):
  bytes_io = BytesIO(msg.encode('utf-8'))
  await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=bytes_io, filename='message.txt'))

Comment: It's in the `io` module, so you need `from io import BytesIO`. The rest of the code should work.